# pip repository APIs

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I'm currently migrating a bunch of internal python code to use setuptools, and accordingly I need to set up an internal repository to host my new packages. I've found several options (mypypi, pypiserver) but nothing that actually documents the APIs that are implemented. Is there an actually useful reference somewhere, or am I stuck reverse engineering the servers I've already found?

Comment: Do you actually need this? Normally you can just use `pip` itself to build local caches, convert them to fake networked sources and/or wedge them into a `devpi` cache, and test and/or install against the result. WHat do you need to do that can't be done that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs can be found [on PyPI itself](https://pypi.python.org/pypi), by clicking the PyPI Developer Info link on the left sidebar.

Currently, this link takes you to [CheeseShopDev](https://wiki.python.org/moin/CheeseShopDev) on the wiki. As noted, this is somewhat out of date. But it's probably never going to be updated, because "as of 2013-11-11, PyPI is undergoing a complete rewrite from scratch".

Eventually, the updated information should be available in the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which should always have the latest docs for anything packaging-related (except at present, in some cases, "latest" means "not yet written"…), as well as linked from PyPI itself.

At any rate, on the wiki page, you can get [a list of XML-RPC endpoints](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPIXmlRpc), and you'll also find a link to [the old APIs](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall#package-index-api), which may or may not still be needed for `setuptools`.

Hopefully that's everything you need?